# Not able to do neptune bulkload from aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-neptune

I am not able to do Neptune bulk load from AWS S3 using curl command?

This is the error I am getting:

```
{"code":"AccessDeniedException","requestId":"f6243cd3-2a4f-48a2-9d91-13803c199ef1","detailedMessage":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Sample Query:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://*******.cluster-c4brigvg3m9m.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/loader -d'
    { 
      "source" : "s3://******/Unsaved/2022/12/13/4a873928-9910-47b0-85ca-de593ace4f4a.csv", 
      "format" : "csv",  
      "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::959061167427:role/NeptuneLoadFroms3", 
      "region" : "us-east-2", 
      "failOnError" : "FALSE",
    }'
```

Comment: Does your cluster have IAM Authentication enabled? If yes, the request will need to be signed. To do that you could use a tool such as AWSCurl, or the Jupyter graph-notebook notebooks.

Comment: yes, My cluster have IAM authentication enabled. Can you share the step for how my request will be signed ?

Answer (score 1):

The curl utility does not have a means to pass IAM credentials. The error message you are getting is because you're using a Neptune cluster with IAM Authentication enabled. To resolve this issue, you can use awscurl [1], a utility that will sign the request with IAM credentials that you pass either directly as parameters, credentials that you have stored as environment variables, or credentials that you have stored as a profile in the AWS CLI.

```
awscurl -X POST --service neptune-db -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --region us-east-2 \
https://**.cluster-c4brigvg3m9m.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/loader -d' 
    {
        "source" : "s3://*/Unsaved/2022/12/13/4a873928-9910-47b0-85ca-de593ace4f4a.csv", 
        "format" : "csv", 
        "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/NeptuneLoadFroms3", 
        "region" : "us-east-2", 
        "failOnError" : "FALSE"
}'
```

1] https://github.com/okigan/awscurl

Comment: Thanks. I did the same and status is 200 for neptune bulk load. But now this error shows when navigate into gremlin console from ec2 instance with neptune endpoint(neptune-remote.yaml file).

Error:
"Error during 'connect' - No such property: conf/neptune-remote.yaml for class: groovy.lang.Binding"

Comment: That sounds like a different issue It looks like you are trying to connect using the Gremlin console. I recommend you open a separate question for that, as that is not going to be related to bulk loading data.